# Change number of products column

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have written the following code and it works properly, but there is a problem and the products are all in the same column when they are displayed, and I need it to be displayed horizontally. [What should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9DxC.png)
[What is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTISZ.png)

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
    <ul class="products">
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 12
                );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                endwhile;
            } else {
                echo __( 'No products found' );
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </ul><!--/.products-->
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to style your **ul** element to display its contents in rows rather than a list.

Try adding

```css
ul.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

to your CSS and see what happens. Refine further if required.